# Possible Multiple AuthenticationSchemes in request header?

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4, dotnet-httpclient, bearer-token

I have two webapis A and B. From A i make a request to B. A contains user info from identityserver4 where i just need to pass the token to the request header. Beside identityserver token, A also uses AAD(Azure Active Directory) where i have registred B. So from A, i also check my AAD so that i can retrieve The token from Azure to send to B, This is just so B can trust that a request is coming from a trusted registred source. As you can understand From A i have two tokens, one to check the loged in user and the other to check registred application. My A startup class look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Config = services.ConfigureAuthConfig<AuthConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AuthConfig"));
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<ICurrentUser, CurrentUser>();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          
           .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(//this coming with identityserver token and user info
                idt =>
                {
                    idt.Authority = "https://gnoauth.se:5005";
                    idt.ApiName = "globalnetworkApi";
                    idt.SaveToken = true;
                    idt.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                }
            );
```

So here is my A httpclienthelper, where i setup my client headers to send to B, As i already have the token and user from identity server so the other thing i do here is to send B authority, client id and secret to AAD for retrieving the second token:

```
var context = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
var accessTokenFromIdentityserver = await 
                context.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
var tokenfromAAD = result.AccessToken;

defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                AuthenticationHeaderValue("AAD_Authentication", tokenfromAAD);
```

from here i actualy have all i need, both the tokens and all claims. As you can see to the defaultrequestheaders i only cansend one token but i would like to send both tokens to B, how can i configure the request headers to be able to do that?

So here is the B startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer("AAD_Authentication", opt =>
            {
                opt.Audience = Configuration["AAD:ResourceId"];
                opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AAD:InstanceId"]}{Configuration["AAD:TenantId"]}";
                opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("IDS4_Authentication",
                idt =>
                {
                    idt.Authority = "https://gnoauth.se:5005";
                    idt.Audience = "globalnetworkApi";
                    idt.SaveToken = true;
                    idt.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                }
            );

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("AAD_Authentication", "IDS4_Authentication")
                .Build();
```

But i also setup a policy so that from some of my controllers i need to authorize both logedin user and application registration like this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AAD_Authentication,IDS4_Authentication", Policy = "MyPolicy")]
```

the big problem i have been facing is how from A to send both tokens and how to setup authenticationschemes so that B actually get two bearer authenticationschemes

ANY HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 1):

It's the first time I see this thing of two authentication schemes at same time. With two JWT Bearer configurations. Usually I saw it with JWT and Cookie, but not with two JWT.

One thing you may notice, is that it's not the same authentication scheme for A than A calling B. In your case, despite A as an API, is really a client asking for authorization on B. With this point of view, you have nothing to do on A authentication to get on B.

You should use an HttpClient or TokenClient with the specific flow each time you want A call an endpoint on B.

The AddAuthentication configuration is to protect A, not for get authorization on B.

Other different matter is that you would like two Identity Providers AAD and IDS. This should use something similar to External Identity Providers.

Maybe I'm wrong or I didn't understand you. But I hope I clarify something about this question.

P.D. Azure Functions Easy Auth has something like "proxy" Identity Provider. I think it's the same idea as External Identity Provider.